# Android's - performHapticFeedback vs Vibrator - documentation and use

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, haptic-feedback

**TL;DR:**

Would appreciate any extra information on Android's

[abstract class Vibrator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator) 
**vs**
[performHapticFeedback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performHapticFeedback(int))

Preferably avoiding the use of the `Vibrator class` and prioritising `performHapticFeedback` to circumvent having to ask the user for permissions, and rely only on their system's preference.

---

**Scenario:**

I'm working with Xamarin trying to implement Haptic Feedback for Android and iOS.

Now, whereas the iOS documentation has a [short explanation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimpactfeedbackgenerator), which I've implemented as the following:

```
    void Platform.Vibrate(HapticsIntensity HapticsIntensity)
    {
      UIKit.UIImpactFeedbackGenerator ImpactFeedbackGenerator;

      switch (HapticsIntensity)
      {
        case HapticsIntensity.Light:
          ImpactFeedbackGenerator = new UIKit.UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(UIKit.UIImpactFeedbackStyle.Light);
          break;
        case HapticsIntensity.Medium:
          ImpactFeedbackGenerator = new UIKit.UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(UIKit.UIImpactFeedbackStyle.Medium);
          break;
        case HapticsIntensity.Heavy:
          ImpactFeedbackGenerator = new UIKit.UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(UIKit.UIImpactFeedbackStyle.Heavy);
          break;
        default:
          ImpactFeedbackGenerator = null;
          break;
      };

      if (ImpactFeedbackGenerator != null)
      {
        ImpactFeedbackGenerator.Prepare();
        ImpactFeedbackGenerator.ImpactOccurred();
      }
    }
```

The Android documentation for [Haptic Feedback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performHapticFeedback(int)) states that the method *performHapticFeedback* expects a *HapticFeedbackConstant* as a parameter.

```
public boolean performHapticFeedback (int feedbackConstant)
```

The available *feedbackConstant*'s are [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/HapticFeedbackConstants.html), but they seem to have no difference between them.

Calling:

**LongPress**

```
Engine.AndroidActivity.Window.DecorView.PerformHapticFeedback(Android.Views.FeedbackConstants.LongPress);
```

has the same effect as
**VirtualKey**

```
Engine.AndroidActivity.Window.DecorView.PerformHapticFeedback(Android.Views.FeedbackConstants.VirtualKey);
```

or 
**KeyboardTap**

```
Engine.AndroidActivity.Window.DecorView.PerformHapticFeedback(Android.Views.FeedbackConstants.KeyboardTap);
```

moreover, some of the *FeedbackConstants* don't even result in haptic feedback.

#### Does anyone know where I could find any more documentation around this matter?

---

The reason why I ask is that I am implementing an abstract layer over Xamarin with [Invention](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CallanHodgskin.InventionExtension) where my intention is to have my method calls like:

```
Vibrate(HapticsIntensity.Light);
```

```
Vibrate(HapticsIntensity.Medium);
```

```
Vibrate(HapticsIntensity.Heavy);
```

This works today, but where on iOS I get the tactile feedback of Light, Medium and Heavy vibration, on Android, I can't differentiate between them.

Now, I know Android has a `Vibrate` class (see [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator)), which allows for granular control; however, to use this I need to add to my manifest or ask for specific permissions for my app (`android.permission.VIBRATE`), and that is not optimal.

---

Also, if I add the `android.permission.VIBRATE` permission to my manifest, it seems like (if the device has Haptic Feedback enabled in its settings), I don't even need to add the `Vibrate()` method call to my buttons` `onClick`; and they will already provide the tactile feedback (*BZZZTT!!1!*).

Answer (score 4):

It totally depends upon if the device OEM has altered ASOP code and the vibration timing arrays in `com.android.internal.R.array` resource to enable a special haptic feedback "engine" that they are using on their device.

By default, the hardware OEMs are only required to support (in hardware) a standard on/off vibration (linear actuator, weighted rotary, etc..), not a "true" haptic feedback one which is normally based upon waveforms.

In comparison to the newer iOS devices (7|8+?), they are using the "Taptic Engine" (fancy speak for an "advanced linear actuator") for haptic feedback and only recently are Android devices "catching" up on the hardware side (new OnePlus, Pixel 3s, etc...) are starting to include more advanced haptic/vibration hardware (whether are not the OEM has done any special with that new hardware, you decide...)

So if you look at ASOP's `PhoneWindowManager.java` you will find that most of the `HapticFeedbackConstants` get lumped into a few `VibrationEffects` constants such as:

```
~~~
VibrationEffect.EFFECT_TICK
VibrationEffect.EFFECT_CLICK
VibrationEffect.EFFECT_HEAVY_CLICK
~~~
```

Look at the source if you want to see what the ASOP default `VibrationEffects` would be for a specific `HapticFeedbackConstants`:

- [PhoneWindowManager.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java)

If you have to provide manual-based haptic for your app for some reason, you can use the Vibrator API and provide the byte array for your on/off timing and then special case it for phone devices at offer more hardware features.

Comment: thank you for your reply!

I thought Android would use a different approach. Something OEM agnostic, such as:

(assuming the device as a simple motor where only on/off are available)

Light: On for 200ms
Medium: On for 500ms 
heavy: On for 1000ms 

I understand I can control that through ```Vibrate```, but I did not want to ask for the VIBRATE permission.

Thanks for [this](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/policy/PhoneWindowManager.java), it really did set me in a better direction,

Comment: Since you mentioned a comparison to apple devices and the "taptic engine" I thought I'd share this article with some interesting relevant info. It'll explain the capabilities of Android haptics: https://medium.com/lofelt/the-keys-to-delivering-better-haptics-on-android-f502403c22e7